# History.JS back button doesn't quite work for first page

Tags: jquery, html, pushstate, history.js

I'm using the history.js to change the URL for the page using `pushState` while changing the content with ajax.

My problem is the initial page I go to doesn't work with the **back** button. The content is not stored or the info I used to get the content is not stored.

If I call the `pushState` on initialization that works, but then I somehow have two entries of that page. So when I hit back, I have to hit back again to get to the main page I came from. Don't know if that makes sense or not. Don't seem to find anything relevant to my particular case on here.

```
$(function() {
    var History = window.History; 
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
        return false;
    }
    if($.url().attr('fragment')){
        var url = $.url().attr('fragment').split("-");
    }else{
        var url = $.url().attr('path').split("-");
    }

    photo_ajax(url[3],url[2],url[4]); //perform ajax content update

    //initialize first page but doesn't quite work as it creates two entries
    //History.pushState({pho_id:url[3],per_id:url[2],a_id:url[4]}, "Viewing Photo", $.url().attr('path')); 

    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
        var State = History.getState();
        photo_ajax(State.data.pho_id,State.data.per_id,State.data.a_id);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).on('click', '[id^="dopho_"]', function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
        event.preventDefault();
        History.pushState({pho_id:id[1],per_id:id[2],a_id:id[3]}, "Viewing Photo", $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out something that does work. If i use `replaceState` instead, then the initialize line works and the double entry doesn't seem to happen. So I will go with this for now.

```
$(function() {
        var History = window.History; 
        if ( !History.enabled ) {
            return false;
        }
        if($.url().attr('fragment')){
            var url = $.url().attr('fragment').split("-");
        }else{
            var url = $.url().attr('path').split("-");
        }

        photo_ajax(url[3],url[2],url[4]); //perform ajax content update

        //initialize first page but doesn't quite work as it creates two entries
        History.replaceState({pho_id:url[3],per_id:url[2],a_id:url[4]}, "Viewing Photo", $.url().attr('path')); 

        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
            var State = History.getState();
            photo_ajax(State.data.pho_id,State.data.per_id,State.data.a_id);
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(document).on('click', '[id^="dopho_"]', function(event){
            var id = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
            event.preventDefault();
            History.pushState({pho_id:id[1],per_id:id[2],a_id:id[3]}, "Viewing Photo", $(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
```